# Explicitly refer to state variables instead of local variables with the same name

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to refer to state variables when a local variable has the same name?

The `this` keyword in Solidity does something else, and I haven't heard of any equivalent keyword.

For example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract escrow {

  address seller;
  address buyer;
  address owner = msg.sender;

  function setup(address seller, address buyer){
    if(msg.sender == owner){
        this.seller = seller;
        this.buyer = buyer;
    }
  }

}
```

I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/973) but no answers to my specific question.

Comment: This" represents the current contract instance. I'm not sure if what you're seeking is possible. In general, we should avoid writing the same name for two different variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't exist in Solidity. What you typically see instead is a leading underscore:

```
address seller;
address buyer;

function setup(address _buyer, address _seller) {
    buyer = _buyer;
    seller = _seller;
}
```

(I assume you didn't mean to write `seller` twice in your code.)

Comment: but this is just a style used to distinct between function arguments and global variables. Is he perhaps requesting for solidity something similar to C++ Scope resolution operator?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my answer to make it clearer. Yes, I believe that's what the original question is asking for, but it doesn't exist in Solidity.

Comment: I can confirm, I haven't seen anything similar either and it would be much easier to just distinct naming wise.